# python for loop with lists

Tags: python, for-loop

I get:

```
if(lst[i]%2!=0):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

from this code:

```
lst=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if(lst[i]%2!=0):
        lst.remove(lst[i])
print(lst)
```

I am trying to print only the even numbers in a list and I do not see a problem with my code
why am I getting this error ?

Comment: you are removing list item hence looping to the end will surely cause index error.

Answer (score 2):

[You should not remove from a list while iterating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating). Use, for instance, a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [slice assignment](https://riptutorial.com/python/example/3048/slice-assignment) to achieve the same modification:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

lst[:] = [x for x in lst if x % 2 == 0]
# or simply (if you don't need to mutate the original list) 
# lst = [x for x in lst if x % 2 == 0]

print(lst)
# [2, 4, 6]
```

This has also better time complexity (linear) whereas the repeated `remove` approach is quadratic.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the item from the original list, you can also split the original list into 2 new lists, evens and odds

```
lst=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
evens = []
odds = []
for i in lst):
    if(i % 2 != 0):
        odds.append(i)
    else:
        evens.append(i)

print(evens)
```